# Heapcrash - seg fault by increment a pointer that points to heap

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void foo() {

    char *a_heap_pointer; 
    a_heap_pointer = (char*)malloc(1 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(a_heap_pointer, "a");  
    printf("%s\n", a_heap_pointer);

    while (1){
      ++a_heap_pointer; 

      a_heap_pointer = (char*)malloc(1 * sizeof(char));
      strcpy(a_heap_pointer, "b");  
      printf("%s\n", a_heap_pointer);
    }
}

int main (void) {
  foo(); 
  return 0; 
}
```

Hi there, I'm trying to make my C program cause a segmentation fault by incrementing a pointer that points at the heap, by 1 byte, repeatedly, until the program crashes. However, as my code stands now it just runs indefinitely? I presume because the heap is so large that it would take awhile for it to run out. How can I make my program break the heap?

Comment: Have you looked at the assembly? The strcpy call already seems like undefined behaviour, as you copy 2 characters into a 1 character long buffer. The compiler might simply optimize this into an infinite loop.

Comment: Also, `++a_heap_pointer` followed immediately by `a_heap_pointer = ...` makes the increment a no-op, and so could be optimized away completely, depending on compiler flags - it's code that has no side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Printing on the screen is very slow compared to in-memory operations, so if you remove the printfs, you will probably not have to wait as long.

But modern computers have a lot of memory, and when you take into account swap space on disk it can be many hundreds of gigabytes. Prepare to wait for a long time.

Also, in C, strings are NUL-terminated, so the strings "a" and "b" both require two chars storage. Therefore your calls to `strcpy` overwrite memory that may be used for other things, so your program's behaviour is undefined. Anything can happen, for example that it gets stuck and never terminates.

And a side note: I'm not sure what effect you expect `++a_heap_pointer;` to have? You increment that pointer, but then you immediately replace the incremented value by the return value from `malloc`, so the result of the increment operation will never be used.

Comment: Is there anyway to start allocating memory somewhere at the top of the heap so I won't have to wait as long for it to crash?

Comment: No. But why not use larger chunks? A megabyte at a time might be reasonable.

Comment: The assignment said in increments of 1 byte. Is there anyway to find out the last address in the heap? What I'm suppose to do is when the program crashes, write down that address that caused the seg fault.

Comment: There is no standard mechanism in C, but your operating system and C environment might have one. Or you could try it first with blocks of one megabyte, and then after that program crashes, try a new one which first allocates as many megabytes as you could successfully allocate, and then goes byte by byte.